# What causes the EB cli to package an app as file name 1 (app-123456-654321.zip) vs file name 2 (9f1b.zip)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a docker container that I am trying to deploy to AWS elastic beanstalk. It can `docker build .` and `eb local run` without problem. I use the elastic beanstalk cli and the `eb deploy` command to package the container according to the `Dockerfile` and the `Dockerrun.aws.json` files and deploy to AWS.

Initially, I was able to successful deploy. Recently, after a few days of working on the contents of the container itself I tried to redeploy an updated version and get an errors, listing my app/container as "degraded".

When my container was successfully deployed, running `eb deploy` created a zip file (stored in an S3 container) with a name such as `app-123456_654321.zip`.

Currently, in it's non-functioning state, the name of the generated zip files are simply 4 characters (digits and letters) such as `0f4d.zip`. I have been unsuccessful in configuring.

I am able to re-download the older archives and successfully redeploy them (with the updates to the contents of the container). This leads me to believe that something related to the elastic beanstalk config has changed that I am unaware of.

Within the project folder and the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file (see sample below), there is no noticeable difference between the good and bad archives, other than the unsuccessful yml has a second `docker` directive within the `branch-defaults` (see below) in addition to the `default` directive.

All this to say, what causes the eb cli to archive as file name 1 (app-123456-654321.zip) vs file name 2 (9f1b.zip). I hope this might shed some light as to what as changed.

---

Sample config.yml file:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: eb-prod
  docker:
    environment: eb-prod
global:
  application_name: eb-docker-app
  default_ec2_keyname: sample-key-file
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.0 running Docker 1.6.2
  default_region: us-west-2
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name used by `eb deploy` is based on the label for the ElasticBeanstalk application version. The [eb deploy documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) says you can specify your own label, but doesn't explain the logic behind the defaults.

If you are using git, I believe the default label is generated from the most recent tag and the git commit hash, which might explain your "app-123456_654321.zip".

If you deploy twice from the same tag, I believe `eb deploy` just uses the commit hash shorthand, which hopefully explains the short versions you see like "0f4d.zip".